# Action Link endpoint not fired

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, action

I have some actions on my app (like Wish and Buy) (i cannot be more specific though i want to). They are linked to action links and they appear on FB properly. I have the action link Buy setip for the Wish action for example. The endpoint is configured to `https://sitename/fb_buy` . Whenever i click on the Buy This Wish link on FB the server doesn't even receive a hit from FB (checking the access log there's nothing).

when i debug the click, there's an error 500 from FB "*Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.* "...

I thought it was temporary, however I've been trying for couple of days now with no luck. I bought an SSL certificates and installed it properly, chrome shows green secure connection, all other https services work like charm...

Don't know what i am doing wrong since as i said Facebook's servers do not even "touch" or attempt to connect mine..

Thanx

Comment: Why would Facebook’s server connect to yours? Links usually work client-side …

Comment: Its a server to server call right? If the user has installed the app: Facebook will make a server-to-server call to the https:// endpoint specified in the App Dashboard for that action link. The call will contain a signed_request parameter with a payload that includes the following data:

Comment: Sorry, must have been somewhere else for a moment … Does your action link URL match your app domain?